# xamarin winphone to uwp migration

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.uwp, xamarin.winphone

I know UWP is the future and it supports more than just mobile.

Even though winphone supports windows 10 as of now in future if another OS release from windows there is no gurantee winphone will support that but UWP will certainly support it.

There is no gurantee if visual studio or xamarin studio will continue to support winphone in future relases as well

I am not aware of UWP can anybody give me some idea on migrating xamarin.winphoone to xamarin.uwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

There's an article in Docs.Microsoft that says that XAML should be straightforward to port and most of View Models and Data Models should be portable (if not all). The article is here: [WP8 to UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-root#approaching-porting-layer-by-layer)

After reading this article, there's an step-by-step tutorial (from Microsoft too) to guide you through the porting: [Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-to-a-uwp-project)

I can't help with personal experience, but I think these articles should help :)

---

## Old Answer

I'll assume that you are using Xamarin.Forms because I don't know of any advantage of writing a winphone-only app using Xamarin.

First of all, Xamarin is planning to take WP8 and WP8.1 out of Xamarin.Forms 3, so it's really better to migrate now ([Xamarin.Forms Roadmap](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85747/xamarin-forms-feature-roadmap/p1)).

Now, going to the question, it really isn't hard to migrate from WP 8/8.1 to UWP, in fact, most renderers that I did with Xamarin.Forms for these platforms were exactly equal. The only difference that I remember to encounter was when dealing with files (UWP has a different File API).

And even adding Xamarin.UWP to your solution isn't hard ([Adding a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/)).

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I am xamarin native :(

Comment: My project runs using the PCL with MVVMlight ... in myproject.winphone I have xaml files and its bindings to pcl ... can I just copy paste all those to uwp ? will uwp support windows 8,8.1 ?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much